# Как хранить данные между вызовами в AlarmManager?

Tags: android

Делаю сервис на `Android`, который каждые N секунд обращается к веб-сервису. Мне необходимо сравнивать ответы от веб-сервиса между собой , типа "предыдущий / текущий". 
Но как хранить данные между ними, ведь каждые N секунд создается новый экземпляр класса, ответственного за обращения к веб-сервису? Если не в нем, то где?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заведите себе объект [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) - ее надо декларировать в манифесте и положите свой `Hashtable` туда, обложите геттерами/сеттерами и все.

Comment: А если система перезапустит приложение, тогда что?

Comment: Ну если надо то можно организовать сериализацию - в чем проблема то? Только сдается мне что в постановке топикстартера такая необходимость вряд ли возникнет.

Comment: а о сериализации ни слова. Поэтому я считаю Ваш ответ немного вредным. Сам видел программу, в которой принята такая же методика. Разрабы ругают андроид, но сделать по правильному не хотят.

Comment: А по мне ваша постановка вопроса - чуть что так сразу сериализовывать вреднее...

Comment: Этот вариант подошел бы больше, но я решил не заморачиваться и свой Hashtable.toString() и положил в SharedPreferences приложения. Хранить ее между запусками приложения мне нет нужды. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: ну, удачи, @fundottz, готовьтесь, что будут странные баги, потому что андроид вероломно перезапустил Ваше приложение. Да, это будет  не частно, но будет доставать.

Comment: Да, токо дешевше чем городить базу...

Answer (score 0):

А где угодно. К примеру, в базе. Или в отдельном файле (все сильно зависит от размера и типа результата).

Я к примеру бы хранил в базе, сделав разбивку на поля. Сравнивать будет достаточно удобно, если каждой записи прицепить время (желательно в utc). Можно и автоинкрементное поле, в большинстве случаев, Вы вряд ли по второму кругу его пустите (но у меня такое было:) ).

Comment: мне необходимо хранить одну Hashtable (предыдущий ответ) и ее постоянно обновлять. Размер данных невелик - до десятка строк всего лишь. Историю ответов хранить не требуется. думаю бд для этих целей использовать как-то громоздко будет) может проще есть варианты?

Comment: как по мне - так база самое оно. Либо, что меньше нравиться - файл.